# Can I specify what video format to use when calling an Android camera intent?

Tags: java, android, video

I windows UWP development, I can choose what format I want the camera to record the video in (i.e. mp4) like:

```
CameraCaptureUI camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
camera.VideoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat.Mp4;
```

I was reading [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html), how to (simply) take videos in Android with and Intent. What is the default format when a video is taken this way? Is there a way I can tell it to record the video in an mp4 as opposed to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the default format when a video is taken this way?

Whatever the camera app wants, out of the multitude of possible camera apps that might process your request.

Remember: when you use `startActivity()` with an implicit `Intent` like `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, usually you are starting up an activity in somebody else's app. Sometimes, the `Intent` is something only the OS will handle, but most times anyone can implement an activity for it. There are hundreds of pre-installed camera apps across the thousands of Android device models, and there are many more camera apps available on the Play Store that might advertise support for your `Intent`.

> Is there a way I can tell it to record the video in an mp4 as opposed to something else?

Not through any documented and supported protocol. There might be some third-party camera apps that offer additional extras where you can provide that information, but few apps will honor them.

Comment: Ok, is there a way I can use `android.hardware.camera2` and create an integrated camera to control the format.

Comment: @James_Parsons: Well, the actual recording will be done by `MediaRecorder`, though you can use the `camera2` classes for setting up the preview and such. You can then choose the [video encoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html) and [output format](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html), possibly subject to some device limitations. However, working with the camera APIs directly is rather complex to get right across all devices, and `camera2` is only for API Level 21+.